# Change something upon action/click

Tags: hyperref, pdf, forms

Is it possible to create things in PDF that can change upon an action (left mouse button click) using LaTeX?

A simple scenario would be that one (me) is trying to create a form and has some checkboxes that need to be ticked off in the form. So the empty box changes to a ticked off box upon a left mouse button click.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
 \framebox(7,7){}

 %changes to

 \framebox(7,7){$\checkmark$}

 %upon click

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Like this?:***

[image]

---

The `hyperref` package provides the command `\CheckBox`.

> You must put your fields inside a Form environment (only one per
>   file).(Ref: [manual for
>   hyperref](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjg8OWKjKfUAhVHliwKHcsVA0MQFggmMAA&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Ftug.ctan.org%2Ftex-archive%2Fmacros%2Flatex%2Fcontrib%2Fhyperref%2Fdoc%2Fmanual.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGQANkf4vxfZQz7P3uqgGyLSZpnHA&cad=rja),
>   not well documented)

*CheckBox macro:*

```
\CheckBox[parameters]{label}
```

The macros creates a checkbox with the identifier `label`.
With the parameter `checkboxsymbol` you can choose a pifont arrows like `\ding{51}` as an alternative to the default arrow (see default checked).

In *Table 2: The characters in the PostScript font Zapf Dingbats* from the manual [Using common PostScript fonts with LATEX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf) you can find more elements. Here you can see a part of this table:

[image]

Here is a short list of other parameters:

- *backgroundcolor* : color of box
- *color* : color of text in box
- *height* : height of field box
- *name* : name of field
- *width* : width of field box
- *checked* : whether option selected by default

... the whole list you can find in *6.2 Forms optional parameters*.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}     
\begin{document}    
\begin{Form}
Before clicking:

\CheckBox[name=A]{Before clicking}\\

After clicking:

\CheckBox[checkboxsymbol=\ding{51},name=B]{After clicking}\\

Default: checked

\CheckBox[name=C,checked]{Default: checked}\\
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

If you want a choice between some options, have a look to the macro `\ChoiceMenu[parameters]{label}{choices}`.